# Best way to archive an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I want to archive a Azure VM. It's currently deallocated, so we're not incurring compute charges, but we're still paying for the storage, even if it's not online. We want to move the storage to BLOB storage since it's cheaper, as we don't want to lose the data, but don't want to pay a premium to have it sit idle, either.

I tried to create an image, which then deleted the VM instance, but left the disks in-tact without a reference to them.

What's the best way to archive a VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If your Disk is managed**, you can take following steps.
Now, Azure can let you change your **Managed Disk** type easily.

**Steps**:Go to Azure Portal> Stop (deallocate) your VM> Go to Your Disk> Account type > Choose standard (HDD)> Click Save

Then your disk will be successfully updated!

[image]

After deleting the VM, you can also use the disk to create VM from the disk. Also, you can  generate a URI for the disk to copy it to another storage account or export it.
[image]
**If your Disk is unmanaged**, you cannot convert the disk from Premium to standard directly. You need to  create a new storage account (or use an existing storage account) and copy the blobs holding the disks from Premium account to Standard account. The best way is that you can use [Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy) to do this.

Comment: I'm trying to go from managed disk to blob storage. We have 5x1TB SSD that are $135/mo each. Going to HDD drops that to $40/mo, but it's still more than than $20/$10/$1 that we'd have to pay if we moved it to hot/cool/archive on the blob. Is the only way to achieve this really to export, download to VM, and then upload to BLOB?

Comment: I can't just snapshot the VM to BLOB store and delete the VM instance?

Comment: Hi,@Robear. The way to achieve your request is not only one.  You can also use snapshot of the disk and can also create a VM from the snapshot. If you want to save more money to achieve that. You can minimize unnecessary costs using snapshot. But the managed disk snapshot is not stored in Blob.

Comment: @Robear , If you have any issue or think about this case, don't be shy to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This comes quite late, but I just struggled with this exact issue. The solution is currently documented by Azure themselves, even though it is surprisingly difficult to search for:

[Export/Copy a managed disk to a storage account using the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/copy-managed-disks-vhd-to-storage-account)

In case the link becomes invalid in the future, here is the key info from this page:

> This script exports the underlying VHD of a managed disk to a storage account in same or different region. It first generates the SAS URI of the managed disk and then uses it to copy the VHD to a storage account.

#### Launch Azure Cloud Shell

#### Sign in to Azure

```bash
subscription="<subscriptionId>" # add subscription here

az account set -s $subscription # ...or use 'az login'
```

#### Run the script

```bash
#Provide the subscription Id where managed disk is created
subscriptionId="<subscriptionId>"

#Provide the name of your resource group where managed disk is created
resourceGroupName=myResourceGroupName

#Provide the managed disk name 
diskName=myDiskName

#Provide Shared Access Signature (SAS) expiry duration in seconds e.g. 3600.
#Know more about SAS here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1
sasExpiryDuration=3600

#Provide storage account name where you want to copy the underlying VHD file of the managed disk. 
storageAccountName=mystorageaccountname

#Name of the storage container where the downloaded VHD will be stored
storageContainerName=mystoragecontainername

#Provide the key of the storage account where you want to copy the VHD 
storageAccountKey=mystorageaccountkey

#Provide the name of the destination VHD file to which the VHD of the managed disk will be copied.
destinationVHDFileName=myvhdfilename.vhd

az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

sas=$(az disk grant-access --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $diskName --duration-in-seconds $sasExpiryDuration --query [accessSas] -o tsv)

az storage blob copy start --destination-blob $destinationVHDFileName --destination-container $storageContainerName --account-name $storageAccountName --account-key $storageAccountKey --source-uri $sas
```

#### Clean up resources

```bash
az group delete --name myResourceGroupName
```